# How to print lines in C terminal after u have passed the line

Tags: c

I know based on the header, my question doesn't make much sense but hopefully the example might.

ex:

```
printf("hello world\n\n\n");
printf("hello again");
printf("bye now");
printf("this should print on line 2");
printf("this should print on line 3");
printf("this should print on line 4");

expected output
1. hello world
2. this should print on line 2
3. this should print on line 3
4. this should print on line 4
5. hello again
6. bye now
```

My goal is to first print out lines 1,5, and 6. And then print out lines 2-4(inclusive), with 1 second in between. I know you can print out the lines with 1 second in between using sleep. But I am not sure how to print lines 2 - 4 after printing out lines 5, and 6.

Comment: You can use "ANSI" cursor-control sequences to move back up the screen.  Or you can use the `ncurses` library.

Comment: Show what you know, explain the deficiencies. I'm having terrible understanding exactly what you want from the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("hello again\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("bye now\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("\033[5A");         /* move up 5 lines */
    printf("but wait\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("there's more\n");
}
```

The magic, of course, is in that line

```
printf("\033[5A");
```

The sequence `\033` prints the ASCII Esc character (octal 33, hex 1b).  And the four-character sequence

```
Esc [ 5 A
```

moves the cursor up 5 lines.

This assumes you have a terminal (or a terminal emulator) that implements the ANSI-standard cursor motion sequences, but most of them do.  (Once upon a time, there were lots of different terminals using lots of different cursor motion conventions, and it was recommended to use the [`termcap`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) and/or [`ncurses`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) packages to insulate your code from those details.)

These ANSI sequences aren't part of (aren't specified by) the C language, but as I say, they tend to work.  The most useful is probably `ESC [ rr ; cc H` which will move to an arbitrary row `rr` and column `cc`.  There are lots more of these sequences; one decent reference I just found is https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797 .

Comment: hey so that worked, nearly. but by the end of the out put, it deletes "hello again" and "bye now"

Comment: @ss2 You could try `\033[3B` at the end to move back down.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks a lot.